# Redirects loading in http instead of https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, server

I am wanting my site to always load in https, which I thought I had setup, but apparently, sometimes during redirects my site still loads http.

I currently have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

My host provider sent me a link which shows the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question is, should I adopt their method or is there something that I could add to my htaccess code so that all redirects will load as https.

Edit: Does anyone know what this piece of code actually does?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `CF-Visitor`

> this header is a JSON object, containing only one key called “scheme”. The meaning is identical to that of X-Forwarded-Proto above - e.g. it will be either HTTP or HTTPS, and it is only  relevant if you need to enable Flexible SSL in your Cloudflare settings.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-CF-Visitor

So , to check it is better to check weather  `htpps` setup on the same server or with cloudfare like that :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Note :** clear browser cache the test

Comment: I do not have the site setup through cloudflare. I was intending to, but never did.